# celery excess argument [True, False] subtask, callback, How do I remove them?

Tags: callback, celery, chord

How to ignore arguments allowed [True, False] when you pass an argument `((status_id))` to function success ()?

```
status_id=11

callback = success.subtask((status_id,))
chord(results)(callback)

@app.task(routing_key="message_status", queue="message_status")

def success(status_id):

    try:
        global db
        db = connection()
        db.query(MessageTask).filter_by(id=status_id).update({
            'status': 'success',
            'date': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        })

        db.commit()
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

status_id comes in result of [[True, False], '11']. How do I remove them?